# edit the value of a variable in a for() loop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, for-loop

I'm making a website where there is a counter of your steps.
**It's a exercice I made for myself since I'm beggining and learning.**
Every second the script is adding one step until it reaches "`steps`" (which is 5 for this exemple)
I would like the user to be able to click *add 100 steps* so it doesn't end at 5.
I'm doing all this with a `for()` because it's the easiest way I found to later update things on the page every steps.

**The story telling is :**

1. The user sees steps going up, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
2. They can click "add 100" to add 100 more steps (so the counter keeps going)
3. the counter is updated and keeps going until 105 (meaning the first 5 + 100 more they just added)
4. If they want, they can add 100 extra steps again (they don't have to wait until the counter reaches 105)
5. and go to 205

It's actually not working and I can't see what is wrong.
I nailed to replace steps with the value of 100 and `console.log()` it to debug a bit. But It's not addind 100 to the previous step value neither updating the `for()` to keep going until 105.

Thanks for the help

```js
let steps = 5;
$( document ).ready(function() {
  
  $(document).on("click", ".add", function() { 
  let steps =  100; // should be actual steps value + 100
  console.log(steps);
      });     
    for (var i = 0; i < steps; i++) { 
        var nbOfSteps = 0 // the numer of steps actually displayed to the user
        setTimeout(function () {
            nbOfSteps++;
            var addSteps = $("<div />", {"class": "steps"})
            .css({})
            .append($("<p>" + nbOfSteps + " steps </p>"))
            .appendTo(".one")
            $(".steps").prev().remove();
 // do some other things here
        }, 1000 * i) //update i every 1000 milliseconds
    }                 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one" id="gauche"></div>
<div class="add"> add 100 steps</div>
```

**EDIT**

So I have been experimenting with

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  let foots = 3;
  let i = 0;
while (i < foots) {
  setInterval(function () {
  console.log(i);
  }, 1000)
  i++;
  if (i > foots) {
    console.log("ping")
  }
}
});
```

as @sirEgghead suggested. But I can't seem to manage do make anything out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional variables of a `for` loop are interpreted once the instruction for the loop is reached.  Changing the value of the variable once inside the loop will not adjust the conditionals stored in memory.  You might be better off working with a `while` loop in this case and breaking out once your conditions are met.

Following this sort of logic means that you can edit `i` and `steps` to your heart's content, and they will be tested with the new values once per iteration.

```js
var maxSteps = 5
var i = 0;
var nbOfSteps = 0;
var timer;

function incrementDoc() {
  nbOfSteps++;
  $("<div />", {
      "class": "maxSteps"
    })
    .css({})
    .append($("<p>" + nbOfSteps + " steps </p>"))
    .appendTo(".one")
  $(".maxSteps").prev().remove();

  if (++i >= maxSteps) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on("click", ".add", function() {
    maxSteps += 100;
    console.log(maxSteps);
  })

  timer = setInterval(incrementDoc, 2000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one" id="gauche"></div>
<div class="add"> add 100 steps</div>
```

Edit: updated example with properly working and tested example.

I did away with the manual loop altogether and let `setInterval` handle the looping.  I also broke your inline function out into a named function for clarity.  Along the way, I renamed `steps` to `maxSteps` just for my own sanity's sake while I was editing.

`setInterval` is basically what you were trying to do with `setTimeout`, but it has a loop built in.  I utilized that, and used `if` to break the loop with `clearInterval()`.  The argument of `clearInterval()` is the name of your variable when you call `setInterval()` - in this case, `timer`.

It's still a little sloppy, but it's working.

[setInterval() reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).

Comment: My apologies for the bad writing.  I'm working on very little sleep.  As such, I may have also misunderstood a key point in question.  Hopefully the answer helps you out.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, I'll try to experiment with what you said.
Stay safe and sleep well!

Comment: Thank you and best of luck!  If I can help you out any further, I'll be happy to do so.  I'll so take a look at this question again once I revive myself a bit.  lol.

Comment: So, ... I have been experimenting and I don't see anything I can do to make that work...
I'm probably getting this wrong...

Comment: Hey, I woke up a bit and looked it over.  I edited my answer to reflect yours, but working.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is working quite well I have to say.
I now need to let the person add more steps even when the `maxSteps` is reached!
You did an awesome work, thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help.  I only wish I would have thought of it the first time around.  I can only blame the lack of sleep, but that's not an excuse.  Good luck on your project!

Comment: well, I could have helped to find this!
I'm still learning so all of this feels like collecting code online, gathering them, making collage, it's actually great, feeling like sculpting.